# Network design: one-to-many high bandwidth transmissions that excludes users

Tags: networking, network-programming, bandwidth, broadcasting

If StackOverflow is the wrong Exchange for this question, please help direct me to the correct one.

#### Short Version

What is the best design for a networking application in which one user transmits a constant, high-bandwidth stream of data to many other addresses?  The solution must not require the uploader to duplicate the packets for each recipient and preferably will not transmit to users that have not been accepted by the transmitter.

#### Long Version

A friend and I have written an application that enables someone to transmit data in real time to one or more recipients that he wants to receive the data.  I have designed the high-level application protocol to use UDP and to encode the data so that each packet can be lost without hurting the use of the rest.  This solution requires managing sockets with each user and sending each packet to every user.

The problem here is that the stream can be very high bandwidth.  The user can modify the settings for how high quality the data he is sending should be, and can end up sending 6 Mbps to each user.  It is unfeasible to expect a user to pay his ISP enough to be allowed to upload such a stream to the preferred minimum of four other users at a time.

We need a way for the transmitter to send a packet exactly once and have each user receive a copy.

We have looked at multicasting.  It may be what we need to use in the end, but we are concerned about the fact that anyone can join any group.  It would be preferable to not allow users we do not want to see the data to not be allowed to join in.  There is also the problem that if multiple transmitters happen to use the same group, viewers may find that they are receiving multiple streams' worth of data when they only want one.

My searching has revealed something IBM published over a decade ago called Explicit Multicast ([Xcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcast)) that looks perfect, but I have yet to find any information to determine whether this technology is commonly supported.  Also, I have not yet seen whether it supports datagrams.

Does anyone know the best way to design an application that meets our needs?

Please keep in mind that we have no funds to support our project.  Solutions need to be free.

#### Edit

In the summary above, I hinted at but failed to explicitly state that this is for a real-time application.  The motivating drive behind the application is to keep the clients/recipients as close together in time as is possible.  If packets are lost or arrive too late to be used in keeping the server and clients in phase, they need to be disregarded.  That is why I designed the application protocol on top of UDP with independent data in each packet.  Even if a client receives only one packet out of 300 for a given time step, it will use what it did get.

I think that I_am_Helpful's recommendation may be a good step in the right direction (or possibly the destination).  I need to do some experimentation to determine whether using a system like Spread will work.  However, I do not think I can budget more than additional 17 ms in transmission time.

If you can think of a system that enables sending unreliable datagrams to a specific group of users (like Spread) for a real-time application ([unlike Spread, see p. 3](http://www.spread.org/docs/guide/users_guide.pdf)), please let me know about it.

Comment: "The solution must not require the uploader to duplicate the packets for each recipient" -- then you are left with only one option...

Comment: @JanDvorak Are you saying that multicasting is the only option?

Comment: Either you send data from multiple locations, or from one. And you've explicitly excluded the former option.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear in my question.  As I stated in the question title, I want a one-to-many network.  That addresses the network's topology but is not the entire design.  Is there a freely available, widely supported transmission protocol that supports my needs?  If not, what is the best way to mitigate the weaknesses of the best option (possibly multicasting)?  Are there other technical considerations in such a solution that I have not written about?  These are the sorts of questions I was hoping to have answered.

Answer (score 0):

> We need a way for the transmitter to send a packet exactly once and
>   have each user receive a copy.

In my limited knowledge, I would say that [Reliable Multicasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_multicast) appears to be one of the viable option for broadcasting in the group. I would like to mention that there are some of the possible Java API's* which could help you achieving the same :

1. [JGroups Java API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JGroups)
2. [The Spread Toolkit](http://www.spread.org/) -> Spread consists of a library that user applications are linked with, a binary daemon which runs on each computer that is part of the processor group, and various utility and demonstration programs.
3. [Appia](http://appia.di.fc.ul.pt/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

<sub>**NOTE : I have never worked with these API's.*</sub>

> It would be preferable to not allow users we do not want to see the
>   data to not be allowed to join in.

They do provide this feature, e.g., Spread supports thousands of groups with different sets of members. It also provides a range of reliability, ordering and stability guarantees for messages. JGroups can be used to create groups of processes whose members can send messages to each other. It also has facilities like group creation and deletion(Group members can be spread across LANs or WANs).

> There is also the problem that if multiple transmitters happen to use
>   the same group, viewers may find that they are receiving multiple
>   streams' worth of data when they only want one.

When you could easily create multiple groups in the same network(using Spread,etc.), then, I believe that would no longer be an issue. It is your responsibility to declassify users into different groups.

I hope the given information helps. Good LUCK.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I followed your answer to read about reliable multicasting and Spread.  Spread could be promising, but I am concerned that its overhead may increase the transmission times of the data.  In all my background of the problem, I forgot to mention that transmission time is more crucial than packet reliability.  I will add that to the question now.  However, if one of the reliability multicast solutions solve my problem without substantial overhead, I will select your answer.

Comment: I agree that there would be a slight overhead; but, Spread(and others) emphasises on robustness and high performance(check the second-last point). Also, everything obviously is working on UDP datagrams, so, there is very less chance of slow transmission. Good Luck @sadakatsu.

Answer (score 0):

Via multicast you achieve exactly you want: **sending each packet once**, but **authentication** seems to be a concern for you.

One possible solution could be simetric cryptography, where the same key is used to encrypt and decrypt. Via TCP your clients connect to a server and fetch the multicast IP Address of the transmission and its associated key, then they join the multicast group and decrypt the incomming transmission.

If you accept a more flexible solution, you could have a server which sends a transmission in real time to a set of distributed servers. Your clients connect to one of these distributed servers via unicast, and after authentication is done, they are inluded in a list of receivers. Each distributed server sends each new transmission packet to each registered client via UDP. in ordinary situations your clients would have the same experience as if it was delivered in a multicast group, but the servers will spend far more bandwidth. Multiple transmission at a time will be allowed, so it could be good for you, and you can have more control, as clients can send signals to the servers, like PAUSE, and etc.